# can we have two log4j.xml inside same application

Tags: slf4j

I am using a logback.xml inside my webapplication.I am going to deploy more than one application inside my container(say tomcat).I need to maintain one common logback.xml file in that container,which need to accessible across all the application.More over I need to access application specific logback.xml. I can able to access my App specific logback.xml.But no idea how to maintain container level logback.xml.

Can anybody help me out??
Thanks 
Raja

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have the same `logback.xml` shared amongst several web applications (WAR) which are in the same Enterprise Archive (EAR). For this purpose, put your `logback.xml` in folder /APP-INF/classes

However, it's as far as I know not possible to share one for the entire container.

Comment: Thanks Foch.However I am loading two logback.xml seperately in my application.One file from my Tomcat container and another one from my application.I could achieve my aim,but the thing is that I am loading twice.I am not sure whether it will make any performance related issues.